# How to get 20 records 20 to 30 from SQL Server in PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

```
select 
   TOP 20 * 
from 
  (select 
     TOP 30 *
   from SavingRecurringMst_Kuber r, BhishiRegistrationMst b,  
        SavingRegistrationMst_Kuber s 
   where 
       RegID = FKRegID and 
       PkSavingRegID = FKSavinRegID ) as T 
ORDER BY 
   Transactionate DESC
```

Comment: What is your actual question ?

Comment: which version of sql server you using

Comment: I want 20 records in each page(In pagination)

Comment: `OFFSET-FETCH` or `Row_Number`

Comment: I am using sql server 2012

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Use orderby & limit in your query.

Comment: you can use limit for that.

Comment: limit not support in sql server

Answer (score 1):

Try this...! 
Pass the start index and end index as parameter from UI.

```
select SLNO, T.*
from  (
         select 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Transactionate DESC) AS SLNO , SavingRecurringMst_Kuber.*
       from SavingRecurringMst_Kuber r, BhishiRegistrationMst b,  
            SavingRegistrationMst_Kuber s 
       where 
           RegID = FKRegID and 
           PkSavingRegID = FKSavinRegID    
       ) as T 
 where T.SLNO >= P_STARTINDEX and T.SLNO <= P_ENDINDEX
```

Comment: I am using this code but not working below error are generate "The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries"

Comment: @jiten i have updated the answer use updated code

Comment: I am using updated code but not working fine

Comment: can you post the code

Comment: select SLNO, T.*
from  (
         select 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Transactionate DESC) AS SLNO , SavingRecurringMst_Kuber.*
       from SavingRecurringMst_Kuber r, BhishiRegistrationMst b,  
            SavingRegistrationMst_Kuber s 
       where 
           RegID = FKRegID and 
           PkSavingRegID = FKSavinRegID    
       ) as T 
 where 20 >= T.SLNO and 30<= T.SLNO

Comment: copy and paste this code where T.SLNO >= 20 and T.SLNO  <= 30

Comment: if this answer is helpful give one upvote make the answer correct

Comment: can i use column name  "Name=FirstName+' '+MiddleName+' '+LastName, RegDate, Amount, installments" but where

Comment: select SLNO, T.*,FirstName,LastName,DOB,Address
from  (
         select 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Transactionate DESC) AS SLNO , SavingRecurringMst_Kuber.*
        from SavingRecurringMst_Kuber r, BhishiRegistrationMst b,   
            SavingRegistrationMst_Kuber s 
       where 
           RegID=FKRegID and 
     PkSavingRegID=FKSavinRegID 
       ) as T
where T.SLNO >= 20 and T.SLNO <= 30 I am using this code adding column name but not working

Comment: change this to T.Firstname,T.Lastname,T.dob, T.address

Comment: I am using this query "select SLNO, T.FirstName,T.LastName,T.DOB,T.Address from ( select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Transactionate DESC) AS SLNO , SavingRecurringMst_Kuber.* from SavingRecurringMst_Kuber r, BhishiRegistrationMst b, SavingRegistrationMst_Kuber s where RegID=FKRegID and PkSavingRegID=FKSavinRegID ) as T where T.SLNO >= 20 and T.SLNO <= 30 " but invalid column name error display "SavingRecurringMst_Kuber' this table records has been displayed but i need to SavingRecurringMst_Kuber table records as well as BhishiRegistrationMst,SavingRegistrationMst_Kuber tables records